# komento comments count at article

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

I'm trying to add komento comments count add to article at below file

```
templates/name-template/html/com_content/article/default.php
```

code

```
                    $query->select(' COUNT(jc.id) AS comments_count, MAX(jc.created) AS comments_date')
                    ->join('LEFT', '#__komento_comments AS jc ON jc.cid = a.id AND jc.component = \'com_content\' AND jc.published = 1');
```

and use this code for fetch

```
<?php echo $this->item->comments_count; ?>
```

but not show comments count ad get error

Comment: Please show us your efforts before posting your question. It is important that this community is not used as a free coding service.  We don't mind pitching in if you are stuck, but if you need a professional developer that is another matter.  Questions that require "hands-on professional development" are off-topic here.  When you edit your question to show your best coding attempt and the reason that it failed to meet your expectations, please also bother to capitalize the word `i` so that nobody else will need to clean up your post. I upvote clear, on-topic questions that don't need editing.

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks for help

Comment: What is the error? Where is the `from()` call? `$this->item` doesn't fetch query results.  Do you also need to extract the most recent date?

Comment: Is `$comments_link` relevant to your question? If not, please remove it.  Looks like you don't need a JOIN.  Do you mean to use FROM instead?

Comment: @mickmackusa $comment_link deleted from code ...i want get comment count  related post from database and show at article

Comment: @mickmackusa eror : Call to a member function select() on null ----- i want just show comment count for every article with php

Comment: When designing a query for a particular result set, it is often easiest to test your attempts within phpMyAdmin before "bringing it to Joomla".  phpMyAdmin will present quick and informative feedback.  Once you have a working query, then it is a simple task of implementing the necessary query building method calls to provide the rendered query that works in phpMyAdmin.  Do you have a working raw query?

Comment: If the trouble is how to write a sql query, then you have a Stackoverflow question.  If you have a working sql query, please refer to my many complete/tested/explained answers which can be found via: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12352+%5Bmysql%5D  If the question is how to properly implement your data into the MVC design pattern, then your attempt is a long way off and my require "hands-on" development.  Please keep working at your question.

Comment: @mickmackusa What do you think the best way to show comment count article?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I think the posted question is Too Broad to answer.  (I'm off to bed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Komento with Joomla, here is a code for counting the number of published comments related to an article:

```
// Context
$currentArticleId = $this->item->id;
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Build the query
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('COUNT(*)');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__komento_comments'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('cid') . ' = ' . $currentArticleId);
$query->andWhere($db->quoteName('published') . ' = 1');

// Get the result
$db->setQuery($query);
$comment_count = $db->loadResult();
```